# How to use hyperledger network cards locally

Tags: hyperledger-composer

On Playground (macOS) I have one network card admin@perishable-network and I can connect to the business network. However the network card is not visible in directory /Users//.composer/cards. Instead I can see  PeerAdmin@hlfv1 there. 
Another problem is that I get an error running composer-rest-server using  PeerAdmin@hlfv1: No business network has been specified for this connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing on playground you created the business network on the Web Browser Connection which means all cards for that business network will be held in your browser local storage not on your file system. Also that business network is running inside your browser, not in a real fabric so you cannot interact with it any other way except through playground (for example you cannot try to connect the rest server to it).

You cannot use PeerAdmin@hlfv1 with the rest server. This is a fabric network card (ie you use it to perform fabric level activities such as install, start, upgrade) not a business network card. You need a business network card (one that has been associated with a business network) in order for the rest server to connect and discover the specific business network in order to generate the rest api.